# Замена backdrop-filter

Tags: javascript, html, css

Нужно размыть только фон у блока. Я знаю, что для этого есть свойство `backdrop-filter`, но оно плохо поддерживается (в частности firefox).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block {
  filter: brightness(0.4);
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/100);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="block">adadwd</div>
```

Как можно размыть только фон у блока в данном примере?

Comment: Всё очень просто. Firefox не браузер давно. На сайте разрешаем нужные user-agent и проблема решена. После подмены типа браузера пользователем это уже его проблемы будут, если что-то не правильно отображается

Comment: Всегда так делал. Firefox много чего не поддерживает. Если кто-то заходит с недобраузера, то перенаправляем пользователя скачать нормальный браузр. (*шёпотом* главное не яндекс)

Comment: Нормальный такой бред

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Свойство `backdrop-filter: blur(5px)` размывает область под элементом (другие элементы под ним), а не фон внутри элемента.

Для размытия элемента есть свойство `filter: blur(5px)`. Чтобы размыть только фон, можно сделать фон отдельным элементом или псевдо-элементом, применить к нему данный фильтр размытия. Чтобы края остались чёткими, нужно сделать этот элемент больше родителя на размер размытия (на практике чуть больше нужно). А у родителя сделать обрезку через `overflow: hidden`.

```css
.block {
  background-size: cover;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.block::after {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/100) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover;
  filter: blur(10px) brightness(0.4);
  position: absolute;
  left: -10px;
  top: -10px;
  right: -10px;
  bottom: -10px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">adadwd</div>
```